# Mysql generated column query work on localhost but not run live server

Tags: mysql

My query is

```
Create table com (
    Share int(10),
    Fee int(10)
);
Alter table com add column comm int GENERATED ALWAYS AS (2*share-fee) STORED;
```

I also try to make column at creating table but not working same error  #1064

Comment: (1) Which error do you get exactly? Please post the entire error message. (2) What is the MySQL versions on your localhost and in your live server? `select version()` can tell you.

Comment: Generated always is v5.7. Many hosted MySQL servers are on v5.6 as default

Comment: Thanks GMB,Claus Bonnhoff && O.jones now I update server issue are solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, locally installed versions of MySQL are more recent than the versions operated by hosting services.  This is your problem.

It's common that production database services run on older versions of software. Why? Databases (the data) typically have longer useful lifespans than versions of database software. Many databases contain data that's many years old. Upgrading software while keeping data intact can be hard work involving planning, testing, and downtime.  Sometimes people just choose to keep using the older software versions, to avoid the work and the risk.

Version 5.6, which does not support `GENERATED ALWAYS` columns, is over seven years old. 5.7 and later do support it.   Ask your hosting service to upgrade to a later version of MySQL. Or, ask them to move your account to a more up-to-date server within their service. Or get another, more up-to-date, hosting service.

Always deploy new projects on the latest production version of database software if you possibly can. That will give you more time before you are forced to upgrade.

In the meantime, you can avoid this kind of deployment problem. Make sure your development version is the same as your production version. @GMB pointed out that the query `SELECT VERSION()` tells you which version is running.